# => in Google Python Example

Tags: python

So I'm new to Python and trying to work through the Google Python online class [[https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions]](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions%5d)

I am running Python 2.7.5 and when I try this example it has issues with the =>.

I've tried searching google for explanations, but have come up empty.  Any help would be appreciated.

Error message below.

```
sandbox$./re-test.py 
  File "./re-test.py", line 8
    match = re.search(r'iii', 'piiig') =>  found, match.group() == "iii"
                                        ^
```

Code for the program is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

## Search for pattern 'iii' in string 'piiig'.
## All of the pattern must match, but it may appear anywhere.
## On success, match.group() is matched text.
match = re.search(r'iii', 'piiig') =>  found, match.group() == "iii"
match = re.search(r'igs', 'piiig') =>  not found, match == None

## . = any char but \n
match = re.search(r'..g', 'piiig') =>  found, match.group() == "iig"

## \d = digit char, \w = word char
match = re.search(r'\d\d\d', 'p123g') =>  found, match.group() == "123"
match = re.search(r'\w\w\w', '@@abcd!!') =>  found, match.group() == "abc"
```

Answer (score 7):

The author is using `=>` to describe the result; it is *not* part of the Python syntax.

Consider it written as the following, where the intent may be more clear:

```
match = re.search(r'iii', 'piiig')  #=> found, match.group() == "iii"
```

Comment: Thank you!!!1  I thought that might be the case, but I am new enough that I don't have the confidence to be sure that was the case.  Since he didn't include the import of 're' I was considering that I might be missing a different import.

Comment: @user3641109 You're welcome. (I find it silly to not move such to comments, as it can add such confusion and prevents the code from being trivially line-copied.)